# Julia Pkg.init() error init ERROR: UndefVarError: init not defined

Tags: julia

I installed Julia, Juno, Atom following this link to my MAC book pro, http://docs.junolab.org/latest/man/installation.html
Then, following a tutorial, I typed `Pkg.init()`in the console. And I got the error message like this:

```
julia> Pkg.init()
ERROR: UndefVarError: init not defined
```

After searching, I gave up of this error and continue with 
`Pkg.updata()`   and `Pkg.add("IJulia")`. It works charmingly.

PS: 
Julia Version 1.0.2
Commit d789231e99 (2018-11-08 20:11 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: macOS (x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8259U CPU @ 2.30GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-6.0.0 (ORCJIT, skylake)
Environment:
  JULIA_EDITOR = atom -a
  JULIA_NUM_THREADS = 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pkg.init` is not a thing since Julia 0.6. You shouldn't have to do anything to initialize the package manager. Consider using a more up-to-date tutorial, or contribute to the one you were following since you figured out the solution!